# Adding action to DOM element added through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

having a slight problem here. I have a post stream on my site, each post has buttons that execute different actions that are setup in my `$(document).ready()` now, to add posts I make an AJAX call that returns the html for the new post element, but the actions in the my previous `$(document).ready()` do not apply to this new element, and adding it in a `$(document).ready()` for the element causes the buttons from the already posted elements to be duplicated.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements that added after documnet ready event don't accept binding events (you call it ations). You may use `.click()` or `.hover()` or `.bind('click', function(){})` and neither works. You can use jQuery [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Using `delegate` is much better because when you use `live` for `click` (for example) it means you'r listening to any `click` happening on your document and determining if it's that `click` you where looking for or not? But with `delegate` you limit the clicks that computer process to find your `click`.

```
$('.myinput').live('click', function(){
     // do something if a click happened and it was on my input
 })

$('.myDiv').delegate('.myinput', 'click', function(){ 
     // do something if a click happened in my div and it was on my input 
})
```

Comment: The delegate method did not work, it didn't activate the action with the newly added DOM element, but the live method did, thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you use `$(selector).live(eventType, handler)` it should add events to all elements matching that selector.. even if they are added after the DOM is loaded:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

like @Mohsen said there was a way to solve this using .live()
now its depreciated and there is alternate way:

How to change depreciated method?

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

link: [jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

I had thesame problem and this last one with ".on" works fine for me.

Maybe someone have thesame problem and use it too